# NativeScript button text colour

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to style a button text colour but it wont change from blue. My html file:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Username" textWrap="true"></Label>
    <TextField hint="Enter Username" text=""></TextField>
    <Label text="Password" textWrap="true"></Label>
    <TextField hint="Enter your password." text="" secure="true"></TextField>
    <Button text="Sign in"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 20;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10;
    margin: 10 0;
}
```

however the button text colour always remains blue, and i can't seem to get it to be white.

Comment: Just remove `text-transform: uppercase;` from button style in your CSS file and the color will be changed. There is some issue while using `text-transform`.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev yeah you were right, this comment is the correct answer if you wanna create it and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to change text color of a Button, while text-transform has been set to uppercase or lowercase, the color of the text would not be applied. This is an issue only for iOS. In regard  to that  I opened new issue in NativeScript repo in GitHub [#2601](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2601)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are styling using the element you should try capitalizing `button` ->

```
Button{
  color: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 20;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10;
    margin: 10 0;
}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be needed